# Why np.load() couldn't read my ndarray data in pickled file?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I am trying to analyze a tensor data, but I could not read the data in picked file by using np.load(). My python code is as follows:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import sktensor as skt
import numpy.random as rn

data = np.ones((10, 8, 3), dtype='int32')  # 3-mode count tensor of size 10 x 8 x 3
##data = skt.dtensor(data)

with open('data.dat', 'w+') as f:    # can be stored as a .dat using pickle 
    pickle.dump(data, f)

with open('data.dat', 'r+') as f:  # can be loaded back in using pickle.load
    tmp = pickle.load(f)
    assert np.allclose(tmp, data)
```

But when I attempted to use np.load() to load the data in data.bat as follows:

```
np.load('G:\data.dat')
```

Some error appears as"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    np.load('D:/GDELT_Tensor/data.dat', mmap_mode = 'r')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 416, in load
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'D:/data.dat' as a pickle.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `pickle.load` pairs with `pickle.dump`, and `np.load` pairs with `np.save`.  There is a certain interplay between pickle and numpy load/save.  `save` uses pickle for things that it can't save as a numeric array.  And the `pickle` of an array is a version of the `save`.   But let the code take care of those details.  Don't mix them yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the pickle module to save NumPy arrays.  Instead, use one of the methods here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

There's even one that uses pickle under the hood, for example:

```
np.save('data.dat', data)
tmp = np.load('data.dat')
```

Another format like CSV or HDF5 might be more suitable for most applications--especially where you might want to interoperate with non-Python systems.

Comment: @刘飞燕: Great.  If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark on the left to "accept" this answer.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.